# Weather skill Azure web test works by itself, doesn't when connected to Virtual Assistant

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I am trying to add the experimental Weather skill to a Virtual Assistant, and test them via Azure Web Test. 
Both the Virtual Assistant and the Weather Skill work as supposed on their own, but if I use botskills connect to attach the skill to the assistant, republish it and test it in Azure, then ask for the weather in the Virtual Assistant it says "Sending...Send failed"

I see a Gateway Timeout error when I check the Channels page.

"There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout"

When using the following command to attach the skill to the Virtual Assistant

botskills connect --botName MyBotName-xxxxx --remoteManifest "https://weatherskill-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/skill/manifest" --luisFolder "(path to skill solution folder)\Deployment\Resources\LU\en\" --cs --verbose

everything looks fine until I get this warning

"Could not configure authentication connection automatically.
There's no Azure Active Directory v2 authentication connection in your Skills manifest."

Could the issue be related to this?
How can I solve it?

Here I post the code requested in the comments.

EDIT: I'd like to mention that the virtual assistant and the skill are in two different Azure resource groups too

FROM THE VIRTUAL ASSISTANT PROJECT:

skills.json:

```
{
    "skills": [
        {
            "id": "WeatherSkill",
            "msaAppId": "obfuscated",
            "name": "WeatherSkill",
            "endpoint": "https://magicbotreplyweatherskill-xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/skill/messages",
            "description": "The weather skill provides an example of displaying the current weather using AccuWeather.",
            "authenticationConnections": [],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "id": "WeatherSkill_getForecast",
                    "definition": {
                        "description": "Showing the weather forecast.",
                        "slots": [
                            {
                                "name": "location",
                                "types": [
                                    "string"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "triggers": {
                            "utteranceSources": [
                                {
                                    "locale": "en",
                                    "source": [
                                        "WeatherSkill#GetForecast"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "oauthConnections": [],
  "microsoftAppId": "obfuscated",
  "microsoftAppPassword": "obfuscated",
  "contentModerator": {
    "key": "obfuscated"
  },
  "qnaMaker": {
    "endpoint": "https://magicbotreplyresourcegroup-qnahost-xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
    "key": "obfuscated"
  },
  "blobStorage": {
    "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=magicbotreplyresourcegro;AccountKey=obfuscated;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "container": "transcripts"
  },
  "applicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "obfuscated"
  },
  "botWebAppName": "MagicBotReplyResourceGroup-xxxxxxx",
  "luis": {
    "accountName": "MagicBotReplyResourceGroup-luis-xxxxxxx",
    "key": "obfuscated",
    "region": "westeurope"
  },
  "cosmosDb": {
    "authKey": "obfuscated",
    "collectionId": "botstate-collection",
    "cosmosDBEndpoint": "https://magicbotreplyresourcegroup-xxxx.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "databaseId": "botstate-db"
  },
  "WeatherApiKey": "obfuscated"
}
```

launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "VirtualAssistantTest1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx/"
    }
  }
}
```

botname_en_dispatch.dispatch:

```
{
  "authoringRegion": "westeurope",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "hierarchical": true,
  "useAllTrainingData": false,
  "dontReviseUtterance": false,
  "copyLuisData": true,
  "normalizeDiacritics": true,
  "services": [
    {
      "intentName": "l_General",
      "appId": "obfuscated",
      "authoringKey": "obfuscated",
      "version": "0.1",
      "region": "westeurope",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "MaGiCBoTen_General",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "intentName": "q_Chitchat",
      "kbId": "obfuscated",
      "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
      "type": "qna",
      "name": "Chitchat",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "intentName": "q_Faq",
      "kbId": "obfuscated",
      "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
      "type": "qna",
      "name": "Faq",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ],
  "serviceIds": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ],
  "appId": "obfuscated",
  "authoringKey": "obfuscated",
  "version": "Dispatch",
  "region": "westeurope",
  "type": "dispatch",
  "name": "MaGiCBoTen_Dispatch"
}
```

cognitivemodels.json:

```
{
  "defaultLocale": "en-us",
  "cognitiveModels": {
    "en": {
      "dispatchModel": {
        "appid": "obfuscated",
        "name": "MagicBotReplyResourceGroupen_Dispatch",
        "authoringkey": "obfuscated",
        "subscriptionkey": "obfuscated",
        "authoringRegion": "westeurope",
        "type": "dispatch",
        "region": "westeurope"
      },
      "languageModels": [
        {
          "region": "westeurope",
          "authoringRegion": "westeurope",
          "subscriptionkey": "obfuscated",
          "name": "MagicBotReplyResourceGroupen_General",
          "appid": "obfuscated",
          "authoringkey": "obfuscated",
          "version": "0.1",
          "id": "General"
        }
      ],
      "knowledgebases": [
        {
          "hostname": "https://magicbotreplyresourcegroup-qnahost-xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
          "name": "Chitchat",
          "kbId": "obfuscated",
          "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
          "id": "Chitchat",
          "endpointKey": "obfuscated"
        },
        {
          "hostname": "https://magicbotreplyresourcegroup-qnahost-xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net",
          "name": "Faq",
          "kbId": "obfuscated",
          "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
          "id": "Faq",
          "endpointKey": "obfuscated"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

FOR THE SKILL PROJECT:

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "oauthConnections": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "provider": ""
    }
  ],
  "WeatherApiKey": "obfuscated",
  "microsoftAppId": "obfuscated",
  "microsoftAppPassword": "obfuscated",
  "blobStorage": {
    "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=magicbotreplyweatherskil;AccountKey=obfuscated;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "container": "transcripts"
  },
  "applicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "obfuscated"
  },
  "luis": {
    "accountName": "magicbotreplyweatherskill-luis-yyyyyyy",
    "key": "obfuscated",
    "region": "westeurope"
  },
  "botWebAppName": "magicbotreplyweatherskill-yyyyyyy",
  "cosmosDb": {
    "authKey": "obfuscated",
    "collectionId": "botstate-collection",
    "cosmosDBEndpoint": "https://magicbotreplyweatherskill-xxxxx.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "databaseId": "botstate-db"
  }
}
```

launchsettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WeatherSkill": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:xxxx/"
    }
  }
}
```

cognitivemodels.json:

```
{
  "defaultLocale": "en-us",
  "cognitiveModels": {
    "en": {
      "languageModels": [
        {
          "id": "General",
          "authoringKey": "obfuscated",
          "version": "0.1",
          "appId": "obfuscated",
          "authoringRegion": "westeurope",
          "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
          "name": "magicbotreplyweatherskillen_General",
          "region": "westeurope"
        },
        {
          "id": "WeatherSkill",
          "authoringKey": "obfuscated",
          "version": "0.1",
          "appId": "obfuscated",
          "authoringRegion": "westeurope",
          "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
          "name": "magicbotreplyweatherskillen_WeatherSkill",
          "region": "westeurope"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and include two sets of code (obfuscating any keys/secrets)? For the main VA bot: skills.json, appsettings.json, launchSettings.json, <botname>en_Dispatch.dispatch & cognitivemodels.json. For the Skill bot: appsettings.json, launchSettings.json & cognitivemodels.json. These are the files that configure how the two bots connect with respect to LUIS, QnA, and Dispatch.

Comment: I edited the post adding the requested files, but I don't understand what gateway is involved in here to give a timeout error between the assistant and its connected skill.

Comment: Could you adjust your obfuscated values to show the first 4 and last 4 characters so I can check they are correctly placed?

Comment: I ended up updating all NUGET packages for the solution, and configuring/redeploying from scratch and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing an integral part in your `botname_en_dispatch.dispatch` file. A fourth service pointing from the `.dispatch` file to the skill's luis file needs to be included, and should look something like the following. You will need to adjust the `path` property so that it can access the `WeatherSkill.luis` file in your skill.

Hope of help!

```
{
  "authoringRegion": "westeurope",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "hierarchical": true,
  "useAllTrainingData": false,
  "dontReviseUtterance": false,
  "copyLuisData": true,
  "normalizeDiacritics": true,
  "services": [
    {
      "intentName": "l_General",
      "appId": "obfuscated",
      "authoringKey": "obfuscated",
      "version": "0.1",
      "region": "westeurope",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "MaGiCBoTen_General",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "intentName": "q_Chitchat",
      "kbId": "obfuscated",
      "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
      "type": "qna",
      "name": "Chitchat",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "intentName": "q_Faq",
      "kbId": "obfuscated",
      "subscriptionKey": "obfuscated",
      "type": "qna",
      "name": "Faq",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "intentName": "WeatherSkill",
      "path": "https://magicbotreplyweatherskill-xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Deployment/Resources/LU/en/WeatherSkill.luis",
      "type": "file",
      "name": "WeatherSkill",
      "id": "4"
    }
  ],
  "serviceIds": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4"
  ],
  "appId": "obfuscated",
  "authoringKey": "obfuscated",
  "version": "Dispatch",
  "region": "westeurope",
  "type": "dispatch",
  "name": "MaGiCBoTen_Dispatch"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I ended up updating all NUGET packages for the solution, and configuring/redeploying from scratch and now it works...